# Secure Pages Domain Access for Drupal 7

Tags: 7, security, domain-access

I ran into a problem using Secure Pages with multiple subdomains. Secure Pages only seems to allow you to put one domain for SSL and not secure pages. I found the following module in Drupal 6, but I'm wondering if there is another project people know about to solve this problem in Drupal 7?

https://drupal.org/project/securepages_domain

Answer (score 2):

You can actually just leave the base URL and Secure URL blank to not have it redirect to an inappropriate subdomain than you're on currently.

To restate my problem, I had multiple subdomains sharing one database where the Secure Pages module was implemented. If I put down a base and secure URL using one subdomain, I would get redirected to that instance from other subdomains not listed there when https was needed for that subdomain.

This is an undocumented solution as far as I'm aware, so I hope it helps someone else out.

Comment: Note to other users that may find this post - make sure any rewriting rules that affect your $base_path are turned off, took me hours to realise this.